# I want to insert rows into history tables from actual tables (parent and child) on insertion of row into actual tables using postgresql trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

**For Example:**

**Consider my original tables are:**

```
    CREATE TABLE employees(
    id  serial primary key,
    first_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(40) NOT NULL
    );



    CREATE TABLE employees_detail
    (
    eid integer NOT NULL,
    id integer,
    first_name character varying(40),
    last_name character varying(40),
    CONSTRAINT employees_detail_pkey PRIMARY KEY (eid),
    CONSTRAINT employees_detail_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES employees (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
    )
```

The above tables have foreign key relation. So when I insert a row into both the tables, at the same time I want to insert them into history tables.

**consider history tables are:**

```
    CREATE TABLE employee_audits (
    id  serial primary key,
    employee_id int4 NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    changed_on timestamp(6) NOT NULL
    )




    CREATE TABLE employee_audits_detail
    (
    eid integer NOT NULL,
    id integer,
    last_name character varying(40),
    changed_on timestamp(6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT employee_audits_detail_pkey PRIMARY KEY (eid),
    CONSTRAINT employee_audits_detail_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES employee_audits (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
    )
```

I have created below trigger to insert into original parent table(**employees**) to history parent table(**employee_audits**). My trigger is as follows:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_last_name_changes()
    RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$
    BEGIN
     IF NEW.last_name <> OLD.last_name THEN
     INSERT INTO employee_audits(employee_id,last_name,changed_on)
     VALUES(OLD.id,OLD.last_name,now());
     END IF;
      RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql

    CREATE TRIGGER last_name_changes
    BEFORE UPDATE 
    ON employees
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_last_name_changes();
```

Same way I want to insert original child table rows into history child table.

Comment: do you mean you want another similar trigger function and trigger on child table?..

Comment: thank you @VaoTsun, With the same function I want to insert them.

Comment: did you try adding `insert into employee_audits_detail select eid,id, last_name from,clock_timestamp() from employees_detail where eid = OLD.eid`?.. or something

Comment: not working @VaoTsun

Comment: errors?........